# Typing `cd ` quickly does produce enter

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, hp-mini

Whenever I type `c`, `d` and `(space)` quickly, the actuall output is `cd(newline)(space)`. This is obviously most problematic while working with console/terminal.

This happens in all applications, with all system keyboard layouts I've tested.

I only have one idea what might cause this: perhaps some bug in the HP mini 5103 keyboard driver?

System Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on HP mini 5103, driver `Standard 101/102-Key or Microsoft Natural PS/2 Keyboard with HP QLB`.

Comment: +1 for providing all necessary information. Have you tried another external keyboard with the MS standard driver? Do you use the normal terminal or some kind of special?

Comment: Also try holding the `c` key down and then typing `d` slowly.

Comment: Right, it's actually triggered when both `c` and `d` are down (does not matter how long) and space is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hardware bug. http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-e-g-Windows-8/Bug-in-keyboard-for-Mini-5103/td-p/321243

It has been fixed in the [January 6 2011 BIOS update](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=0&prodSeriesId=4256301&prodNameId=4256203&swEnvOID=4055&swLang=5&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=ob-91404-1).

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this on a LiveCD from Ubuntu or something. If the same problem exists then you know it's hardware related.